# Paging design recommendation for asp.net and sqlserver 2005

Tags: asp.net, sql, sql-server, paging

I am relatively new to programming.  My work basically revolves around data and analysis.  I want to create a simple asp.net page which shows huge chunk of data from the database. There could be a millions of rows of data which is used for different kinds of analysis/searchin/filtering etc..

Should I write paging logic at the front end or at the back-end (in this case SQL Server 2005)?

What would be the best practice around this? Your suggestions/links to resources in this direction is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you using LINQ-to-SQL are rolling your own data access code?

Comment: Haven't used LINQ-to-SQL yet?

Comment: http://aspdotnet-example.blogspot.com/2011/05/using-store-procedure-customize-paging.html
and
http://aspdotnet-example.blogspot.com/2011/05/customize-paging-in-datalist-data.html Now your work Done!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please  use this example [Building Custom Paging with LINQ, ListView, DataPager and ObjectDataSource](http://mosesofegypt.net/post/Building-Custom-Paging-with-LINQ2c-ListView2c-DataPager-and-ObjectDataSource.aspx)

[Paging of Large Resultsets in ASP.NET](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/PagingLarge.aspx)
ListView and DataPager

[Custom paging in ASP.NET with ListView & DataPager](http://thibautvs.com/blog/?p=718)

[Implementing Custom Paging in ASP.NET with SQL Server 2005](http://www.dotnetfunda.com/articles/article95.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You may be interested in this...
[Paging of Large resultset in asp.net](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/PagingLarge.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you create a stored procedure to query and page your data. Linq To SQL is a fast an easy way to execute the stp.

Simple example of stored procedure to take care of paging:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[stp_PagingSample]
(
    @page int,
    @pagesize int
)
AS

WITH Numbered AS
(
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ID) AS 'RowNumber'
    FROM tbl_YourTable
) 
SELECT * 
FROM Numbered
WHERE RowNumber BETWEEN ((@page - 1) * @pagesize) + 1 AND (@page * @pagesize);
```

The stored procedure is the tricky part. But drop a comment if you would like me to add more sample code executing the stp and rendering the data... :)